# Why does it always say "Requires Installation of Untrusted Packages" and not let me download?

Tags: software-center

As the Title above asks, Why can't I install any packages? I tried installing emesene (Other applications wont install either, just using emesene as an example) but It wont download due to "Untrusted Packages" and gives me "emesene python-libmimic" when I click Details.

What's wrong? Before this I have installed things like KTorrent, VLC Media Player, Audacity and the like but since then nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

Dont worry. Figured out the problem. I looked at my software sources again and noticed that the required sources were not ticked. Which raises the question, how were they unticked if I never touched them until now?

Comment: It is entirely up to you what sources you trust - on standard installations these are few only ;)

Comment: Your understanding of the problem is not correct, the "Requires installation of Untrusted packages" message is related to sources which are enabled but for which you don't have a GPG key (which you must import to trust). If enabling other sources resolved the error it is most likely because you have enabled trusted sources which provide newer versions for the same packages.