# Software Centre will not download software

Tags: 11.10, software-center

Software Centre will not download anything at all. Gives an error message saying it 'Failed to download package - Check internet connection'. And, sometimes, if you try again, 'involves downloading untrusted packages'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15099/why-does-it-always-say-requires-installation-of-untrusted-packages-and-not-let

Answer (score 1):

[Software Center not downloading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70553/software-center-not-downloading) .

Failed to download package files.

Check your Internet connection..

---

Run the following commands (saves a backup of the old lists and creates a new lists folder) and the BADSIG error does not occur:

```
cd /var/lib/apt .
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get update
```