# Requires untrusted packages - adobe flash player

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Adobe Flash player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player)
>   [Why does it always say “Requires Installation of Untrusted Packages” and not let me download?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15099/why-does-it-always-say-requires-installation-of-untrusted-packages-and-not-let)

I am new to this and could really use some help. I have tried looking online but I don't understand what I need to do to fix this. My knowledge is very basic. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is it that you want to fix?.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this same problem on my machine, but it happens when I try to install anything. The workaround I use is to install the application through the terminal instead. Open a terminal (ctrl + alt + T) and run the following command: `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`. Enter your password when prompted, then answer 'y' to the next two prompts. After the program downloads and installs flash player  you can close the terminal. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, that did it. Where do you guys learn how to do stuff like that? I'm in a c++ class, but I'm still just a very basic beginnger.

Comment: Ah, this one was easy. 'sudo apt-get install `,'programname*` is the way to install any program through the terminal. Take a Linux command line class, or find something on YouTube.

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll def try to. Btw, I am having the same problem with installing eclipse. Is is the same easy fix?

Comment: Yep, sudo apt-get install eclipse. Same problem for me, don't know what causes it yet.

Comment: Thank you very much. Hopefully one day I am good enough to help others as well.

Comment: Your'e welcome.